# sqlite and tweepy code in python

Tags: python, sqlite, tweepy

I have a list of users of twitter in the database and r[0] represents their Twitter IDS.
I want to use these IDs to find the user IDs of their followers.

```
con = lite.connect('influence.db')
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    var = cur.execute("select * from users")
    for r in var :
        print r[0]
        result = tweepy.api.friends(r[0])
        for a in result:
            print I ," ", a.id," ",a.name, " ",a.followers_count," ",a.friends_count,"      ",a.statuses_count," "
            I = I + 1
            if a.followers_count>100000:
            cur.execute("INSERT or IGNORE into users1 values (%s,'%s',%s,%s,%s)" %    (convert(a.id),convert(a.name),convert(a.followers_count),convert(a.friends_count),convert(a.statuses_count)))
con.commit()
```

This code does not run for all IDs in the database. Just works for the first ID and stops. I am new to python and sqlite. I want the code to run for all IDs. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the cursor when you execute the `insert` deep in the loop.  Fairly certain that will lose the remaining rows from your original query.

See the accepted answer at [Using multiple cursors in a nested loop in sqlite3 from python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237788/using-multiple-cursors-in-a-nested-loop-in-sqlite3-from-python-2-7) for an example of batching up the inserts statements and running them all at once after the select loop is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can try executemany, like so:

```
con = lite.connect('influence.db')
cur = con.cursor()
var = cur.execute("select * from users")
data = []
for r in var :
    print r[0]
    result = tweepy.api.friends(r[0])
    for a in result:
        if a.followers_count>100000:
            data.append((convert(a.id), 
                         convert(a.name), 
                         convert(a.followers_count), 
                         convert(a.friends_count), 
                         convert(a.statuses_count)))

if data:
    strq = ','.join("?" for i in data[0])
    sql = 'insert or ignore into users1 values (%s)' % strq
    cur.executemany(sql, data)    
    con.commit()

con.close()
```