# Python 2.7 nested cursor: select -> insert

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to do what is claimed as not possible in this thread: 
[Using multiple cursors in a nested loop in sqlite3 from python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237788/using-multiple-cursors-in-a-nested-loop-in-sqlite3-from-python-2-7)

That is, I want a select cursor that I look through and do inserts into another table. Is this really not possible? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using multiple cursors in a nested loop in sqlite3 from python-2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237788/using-multiple-cursors-in-a-nested-loop-in-sqlite3-from-python-2-7)