# Execute python code efficiently on rows in SQLite3 table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a large table (`table1`, columns are `name`, `key`, `info`) with ~1,000,000 rows on which I need to perform the following:

1. Select all rows in which `info` is `Null` or `""`
2. Execute a conversion function in Python 3 that converts `name` to `info` (let's call it `conversion(name)`)
3. Update the row with the new `info` value

What is the fastest way to perform this update? Are there any SQLite3 settings which could be activated to improve performance?

My current research has suggested the following with the SQLite3 library:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT longkey, name FROM table1 WHERE info IS NULL or info = "";')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
items = []
for row in rows:
    # Convert name to info
    info = conversion(row[1])
    items.append(info,row[0])
cursor.executemany('UPDATE table1 SET info = ? WHERE longkey = ?;',items)
```

The problem with this of course is the creation of the list `rows` which is enormous and very memory intensive.

I have considered multiple cursors but this [seems to not be a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237788/using-multiple-cursors-in-a-nested-loop-in-sqlite3-from-python-2-7).

Edit: Is using `connection.create_function(name, num_params, func)` a possible solution to this?

How can I optimise this process to be fast but not extremely memory intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function directly from SQLite, the rows are updated one by one:

```
db.create_function('conversion', 1, conversion)
cursor.execute("UPDATE table1 SET info = conversion(name);")
```

Comment: thanks. will this be most efficient method for the update then?