# Python SQLite3: why does indenting the conn.commit() statement have this impact?

Tags: python, sqlite

I create a simple SQLite table as follows:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_file = '/Users/Dom/Desktop/Test.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Results(Col1 text, Col2 text)''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ListIDTable(Int numeric, ID text)''')

values_to_insert = [(1,"1a"), (2,"1b"), (3,"2a"), (4,"2b"), (5,"3a"), 
(6,"3b"), (7,"4a"), (8,"4b"), (9,"5a"), (10,"5b"), (11,"6a"), (12,"6b"),
(13,"7a"), (14,"7b") ]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO ListIdTable (Int, ID) values (?,?)",
values_to_insert)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Everything looks good.
I then loop through the table created above as follows:

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = '/Users/Dom/Desktop/Test.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
c2 = conn.cursor()

c.execute('select * from ListIDTable ORDER BY Int ASC')
for r in c:
    TblInt = r['Int']
    print (TblInt)

    c2.execute("INSERT INTO Results (Col1 , Col2) values (?,?)", ("XXX",
    "YYY"))
    conn.commit()
```

I expect an output of:
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6..." etc.

However, I get:
"1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6..." etc.

When I remove the indent of the final conn.commit() statement, I get the expected output.
Can someone help me understand why just the "1 & 2" are repeated, but everything then proceeds as normal?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this, `1` and `2` are not repeated. Are you **certain** there is nothing else in your actual code that could be producing extra output you are mistaking for loop output? And can you tell us the output of the following expression? `import sys,sqlite3;print(sys.version_info, sqlite3.version_info, sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)`?

Comment: This is the output of your code you asked for: 'sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0) (2, 6, 0) (3, 8, 11)'.  And yes, I just checked everything I submitted above and re-ran on my end.  I got the same results.

Comment: Ah, no, I tested with Python 3.6, not 3.5. I just reproduced the output. Investigating.

Comment: Looks like this issue might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237788/using-multiple-cursors-in-a-nested-loop-in-sqlite3-from-python-2-7

Comment: Yes, that does look related. I haven't had time to investigate why 3.6 has this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following page identify and explain the issue:
[Using multiple cursors in a nested loop in sqlite3 from python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237788/using-multiple-cursors-in-a-nested-loop-in-sqlite3-from-python-2-7)

To fix the above question, I essentially pulled the entire lookup table and eliminated the need for multiple cursors:

```
import sqlite3
sqlite_file = '/Users/Dom/Desktop/Test.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('select * from ListIDTable ORDER BY Int ASC')
rows = c.fetchall()

for r in rows:
    TblInt = r['Int']
    print (TblInt)

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Results (Col1 , Col2) values (?,?)", ("XXX", 
    "YYY"))
    conn.commit()
```